# padding whole data frame values in python

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I am trying to pad the df:

[image: df:]

I define the max length as:

```
mx=new.groupby("COW_NUM").size().max()
```

and trying both:

```
pd.DataFrame([np.pad(x, (0, mx - len(x)), 'constant') for x in list_new.values],index=list_new.index)
```

which lead to extra columns and not correct padding
I also try:

```
pad_sequences(list_new.values, maxlen=mx, value=0).tolist()
```

which lead to Error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

what I doing worng?

Comment: ok but what are you trying to do?

Comment: as i mentioned I trying:  pd.DataFrame([np.pad(x, (0, mx - len(x)), 'constant') for x in list_new.values],index=list_new.index) and the padding worng probaly because df.values is nested list